# make endpath to lowercase in nginx using lua module

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to make request url to lowercase before setting it for proxy pass.

here is my nginx file

```
location ^~ /admin/(?<endpath>.*)
            {
                set_by_lua     ngx.var.endpath string.lower(ngx.var.endpath)
                proxy_pass     http://api.sample.com/api/portal/admin/$endpath$is_args$args;
            }
```

But I am getting error: **invalid variable name "ngx.var.endpath"**

Comment: where did you create that variable?

Comment: @Piglet: as my location is `^~ /admin/(?<endpath>.*)` so `ngx.var` should have `endpath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know nginx very well but from according to the [docs](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#set_by_lua) the lua code should be a string.

So instead of

```
set_by_lua     ngx.var.endpath string.lower(ngx.var.endpath)
```

try something like

```
set_by_lua $endpath 'return string.lower(ngx.var.endpath)'
```